# mmap persistence in linux

Tags: linux, unix

If I mmap a file does this mapping last across boots? Do I need to remmap after each boot?

Comment: `mmap` is not persistent. You can use `msync` to synchronize your `mmap`ed data with physical storage.

Comment: I understand that I need to use msync to sync the data to disk. My question is if I mmap a file, reboot, then access those memory addresses it was mapped to before reboot will it load the file off disk? Does it "remember" the mapping?

Comment: I'm curious why you thought mmap might last across boots, or even extend to another process.

Comment: Just reading up on them and was unable to find an answer to that question. They can be accessed by another process with the flag MAP_SHARED.

Comment: `MAP_SHARED` means that the changes will be written back to the underlying file.  Thus someone else could open the file and `mmap` it as well.  It's not so much sharing the *map* as sharing the *changes*.  With `MAP_PRIVATE` it's as if you read the file into a private buffer.  Other processes can still `mmap` the file, they just see it unmodified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not remembered. After the program exits it's memory maps are gone.